# How to check the data already exists or not laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have 2 tables. Patient table and reservation table.

Patient table:

- ID
- name
- medical record number (norekmed)

Table of reservations

- ID
- idpatient
- idroom

How do I check patient data already or not if I make a reservation?

Checking is by comparing between a reservation form field with norekmed in the patient table.

If patient data already exists, we can make a reservation. And if there is no patient data, we cannot make a reservation.

If it turns out this is not good, and there is a better method, I accept that.

**Reservation controller (store)**

```
$this->validate($request,
            [
                'idpatient' => 'required|unique:reservation,idpatient',
                'idroom' => 'required',
            ]);

        Patient::where(function($query) { 
            $query->has('id')
            ->orHas('norekmed');
        })->find(1);

        $reservasi = new Reservasi();
        $reservasi->idpatient = $request->idpatient;
        $reservasi->idroom = $request->idroom;
        $reservasi->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution could be to use [`firstOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) and let the validator check if the patient id and room id [exist](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists). If I would have done this I would do the following:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    // This will check if the patient exists.
    'idpatient' => 'required|exists:patients,id',
    // This will check if the room exists.
    'idroom' => 'required|exists:room,id',
]);

// Get the reservation or create one if it does not exist.
$reservasi = Reservasi::firstOrCreate([
    'idpatient' => $request->idpatient,
    'idroom' => $request->idroom,
]);

...
```